# "This field is required" when sending POST request to Django Rest Framework API

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a new `Category`, which simply has `name` field to be filled up, but it insists on showing the error saying it's required.

**models.py**:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=32)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Category.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoryList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        """
        Gets all the existing categories
        :param request:
        :return: Category
        """
        categories = Category.objects.all().filter().order_by("name")
        serializer = CategorySerializer(categories, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        """
        Create one new category
        :param request:
        :return: Category
        """
        serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Priting `request.data` shows me, for example: `{'data': {'name': 'Withdrawal'}}`. It shows the data are being sent and received but I don't understand why this errors shows up.

Comment: If that is exactly what is printed, then you are wrapping the values in an unnecessary `data` dict.

Comment: Oh, your comment helped me. I found the solution, I shall write down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out thanks to Daniel Roseman. It happens that I'm using React and Redux, and my action was the following:

```
export function createCategory({ data }) {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      endpoint: '/api/categories/',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({data}),
      types: [CREATE_CATEGORY, CREATE_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, CREATE_CATEGORY_FAILURE],
    },
  }
}
```

The solution was to remove the curly braces within `body` attribute.